# Testing PBEKeySpec junit

Tags: java, passwords, junit5

I am wondering how, or if I should, test .clearPassword() when I use PBEKeySpec to create a secure password? Can I somehow see if my internal copy still exists after .clearPassword()?

Answer (score 1):

After calling clearPassword() calling getPassword() should throw an exception. That’s what you can assert in a test.